# How to insert images dynamically to DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to preload images by creating dynamically div and appending to it image object, but unfortunately divs are created but images are not being attached to them. Here's the code:

```
var preLoadImages = function(im) {
    var args_len = im.length;
    var slides = $('.slides');
    for (var i = args_len; i--;) {
        var img = $('<img>', {
            src : 'img/' + im[i] + '.jpg',
            alt : kp.imgAlt[i]
        })
      img.load(function(){
        (function(index){ 
            kp.cache.push(img);
            var toAppend = $('<div class="slide"></div>')
                            .css({'z-index' : (args_len - index) + 'px'})
                            .append(kp.cache[index]);
            slides.append(toAppend);
            kp.setTimer();
            kp.startSlideshow();
            if(i == 0){
                $('.slides #cover').fadeOut(800, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        })(i);
      });

    }
  };
```

What am I doing wrong? When I'm debugging page with Firebug it shows me that images are created properly and exists in `kp.cache` variable.

Comment: You are not appending images in the slides object, I don't know if you want to.

Comment: I'm appending image to toAppend variable and then toAppend variable to slides object

Comment: I don't see where you are appending them on toAppend. You are pushing them in the cache object, but nothing else. Maybe that is your problem. Isn't it?

Comment: var toAppend = $('<div class="slide"></div>')
                            .css({'z-index' : (args_len - index) + 'px'})
                            .append(kp.cache[index]);

Comment: A fiddle demonstrating the bug would help, I think this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example